# How to make sidebar height to be dependent of the content height?

Tags: html, css

I have a task to build a sidebar, whose height is equal to the content one. 
The more content is, the bigger sidebar is.

In reality, my sidebar is equal to the window size, not content. If I scroll the page down, there is no sidebar on it.

That's me code:

HTML:

```
<div class = "container" style = "height :100%">
  <div class = "row" style = "height:100%">
    <div class = "col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm" style = "height:100%">
      <div class = "sidebar">
       .........
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html .sidebar,
body .sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
}
```

Why? What to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

If I get what you mean properly, then you want the sidebar to be fixed?

In order to do this you can do something a bit like this in the css..

```css
.sidebar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">

</div>
```

Comment: No worries, please accept as correct answer @Aleks339 :)